# How can I use Spark join operations to combine two dataframe into getting a new one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here are my two input PySpark DataFrames

DataFrame1

```
li = [('abc', 'xyz')]
liColumns = ["aid", "bid"]
tempDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=li, schema = liColumns)
tempDF.printSchema()
tempDF.show(truncate=False)
+---+---+
|aid|bid|
+---+---+
|abc|xyz|
+---+---+
```

DataFrame2

```
other_li = [('abc', '111', 'desc111'), ('abc', '112', 'desc112'), ('xyz', 'A123', 'city'), ('xyz', 'A456', 'state'), ('xyz', 'A789', 'zip')]
otherColumns = ['real_aid', 'code', 'some_value']
otherDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=other_li, schema = otherColumns)
otherDF.printSchema()
otherDF.show(truncate=False)
+--------+----+----------+
|real_aid|code|some_value|
+--------+----+----------+
|abc     |111 |desc111   |
|abc     |112 |desc112   |
|xyz     |A123|city      |
|xyz     |A456|state     |
|xyz     |A789|zip       |
+--------+----+----------+
```

**Question**: how can I combine the two to obtain the third DataFrame. I understand how this can be done using append/union but is there a way to do this using joins? Or there is a way to do this more efficiently? I need to do this on two large tables.

Expected DataFrame

```
output_li = [('abc', '111', 'desc111'), ('abc', '112', 'desc112'), ('abc', 'A123', 'city'), ('abc', 'A456', 'state'), ('abc', 'A789', 'zip'), ('xyz', 'A123', 'city'), ('xyz', 'A456', 'state'), ('xyz', 'A789', 'zip')]
otherColumns = ['real_aid', 'code', 'some_value']
otherDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=output_li, schema = otherColumns)
otherDF.printSchema()
otherDF.show(truncate=False)
+--------+----+----------+
|real_aid|code|some_value|
+--------+----+----------+
|abc     |111 |desc111   |
|abc     |112 |desc112   |
|abc     |A123|city      |
|abc     |A456|state     |
|abc     |A789|zip       |
|xyz     |A123|city      |
|xyz     |A456|state     |
|xyz     |A789|zip       |
+--------+----+----------+
```

Comment: Can you be clearer on your objective? Interpreting your intended result it looks as if you want to expand the values of `abc` only out based on the row values of `xyz`

Comment: what is the logic behind how you are combining the two dataframes? can you explain in your question?

Comment: @Chris and Derek - yes, I want to expand the values of "abc" based on row values of xyz. If the two dataframes 1 & 2 can be joined bid and real_aid then we need to expand the rows. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to join the two dataframe based on the `real_aid` and `bid` columns. Then, if `aid` is not equal to `real_aid`, you want to "expand" the row.

You can do it this way:

```py
tempDF\
    .withColumnRenamed("bid", "real_aid")\
    .join(otherDF, ['real_aid'], "right")\
    .withColumn("real_aid", F.explode(F.array("real_aid", "aid")))\
    .drop("aid")\
    .filter(F.col("real_aid").isNotNull())\
    .show()
```

```
+--------+----+----------+
|real_aid|code|some_value|
+--------+----+----------+
|     abc| 111|   desc111|
|     abc| 112|   desc112|
|     xyz|A123|      city|
|     abc|A123|      city|
|     xyz|A456|     state|
|     abc|A456|     state|
|     xyz|A789|       zip|
|     abc|A789|       zip|
+--------+----+----------+
```